# Get first element of nested array for hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Supposing I have an array that looks like:

```
[
  [["str1"],["val1"],["val2"]],
  [["str2"], ["val1"], ["val2"], ["val3"]]
]
```

Is there a way for me to get a Hash that looks like:

```
{
  "str1" => [["val1"],["val2"]],
  "str2" => [["val1"],["val2"],["val3"]]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.map { |a| [a.first.first, a.drop(1)] }.to_h
# or
a.each_with_object({}) {|a, h| h[a.first.first] = a.drop(1) }
#=> {
#     "str1"=>[["val1"], ["val2"]],
#     "str2"=>[["val1"], ["val2"], ["val3"]]
#   }
```

If you do not want to have each element in a separate array:

```
Hash[a.map(&:flatten).map { |a| [a.first, a.drop(1)] }]
#=> {"str1"=>["val1", "val2"], "str2"=>["val1", "val2", "val3"]}
```

Comment: the last one isn't wrapping each element in an array, like the first two.

Comment: Thank you! I used Hash. I've been trying to use to_h for the past two hours but to no avail.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim I should have stated that but I do not want each element wrapped in an array

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim you're totally correct, will add a comment near! Friday, evening.. ;)

Comment: @IronCode if you don't need to wrap each element inside an array, I'd go for @andrey last option. There's also this: `a.map(&:flatten).each_with_object({}){|el, memo| memo[el.shift] = el}`

Answer (score 2):

If your array is `arr`, you could write the following.

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr)).map { |a| [a.shift.first, a.map(&:first)] }.to_h
  #=> {"str1"=>["val1", "val2"],
  #     "str2"=>["val1", "val2", "val3"]}
```

A slight variation would be:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr)).map { |a| [a.shift.first, a] }.to_h
  #=> {"str1"=>["val1", "val2"],
  #     "str2"=>["val1", "val2", "val3"]}
```

Note: We're using the [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Marshal.html) class to make an exact copy of `arr` to avoid modifying the original array. [Object#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) or [Object#clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-clone) won't work here.

Comment: `"str1"` and `"str2"` should be keys and not be present in values from what I understood

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey. I can't test now l. Does my edit look correct?

Comment: yep, it does produce the expected result now (tested) :)

Comment: just a curiosity - how did your post become community wiki? I mean, I did not have any exp with community wiki, so have no idea how it works (the question is not urgent, so answer when you have a moment :))

Comment: @CarySwoveland I kinda hijacked your answer, hope you approve:/

Comment: @sagarpandya82, no problem. My original answer, which I posted from a phone, was not one of my better efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  [["str1"],["val1"],["val2"]],
  [["str2"], ["val1"], ["val2"], ["val3"]]
]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |((k), *values), h| h[k]=values }
  #=> {"str1"=>[["val1"], ["val2"]], "str2"=>[["val1"], ["val2"], ["val3"]]}
```

This illustrates how Ruby's use of *parallel assignment* for determining the values of block variables can be used to advantage.